# Mongodb: Get all documents matching two arrays at same index

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a mongo query that will allow me to find all documents that match values in two arrays at the same index and can't find my way in the documentation.
Say that we have the following data:

```
db.items.insertMany([
{ item1: 1, item2: 5},
{ item1: 1, item2: 2},
{ item1: 3, item2: 3},
{ item1: 3, item2: 4}
]);
```

I would like to get the documents where item1 matches $in:[1,3] and items 2 matches:

- $in:[2,4] if item1 matches first index of $in:[**1**,3]
  or
- $in:[3,5] if item1 matches second index of $in:[1,**3**]

The result in this case would be:

```
{item1: 1, item2: 2}
{item1: 3, item2: 3}
```

In other terms I would like a request that does this:

```
find({"item1": {$in:[x,...,n]}, "item2": {$in:[[y,...,m],...[z,...,l]]}})
```

but with a match on array index. Is it possible or do I necessarily have to perform my request in two steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below find query.

Just create a `$or` combination for different indexes while anding the criteria for each index on item1 and item2

```
find({$or:[{"item1.0":1, "item2.0": {$in:[2,4]}}, {"item1.1":3, "item2.1": {$in:[3,5]}}]})
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question because the values provided were just an example, I was looking for something more generic.

Comment: Np. You don't need to call multiple queries. Just build the query, or the criteria together and send them over to server in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided I won't try to build a mongo query, instead I prepared the list so that I can parse it in a for loop. I have no idea if performances would be better with a mongo query.

In my example key_list would be:

```
var key_list=[{item1_value:1, item2_value:[2,4]},{item1_value:3, item2_value:[3,5]}]
```

And the following loop would get my results

```
var promises = [];
for(var i = 0; i < keys_list.length; i++){
    promises.push(db.getCollection('items').find({"item1": keys_list[i].item1_value, "item2":{$in:keys_list[i].item2_value}}));
}
Q.all(promises).then(function(all_results)){
```